# Understanding rm command

Tags: command-line, rm

I've been using Ubuntu server at home for a while now, and I've noticed I've some holes in my knowledge of bash and in general several dangerous tools like rm.

It is first time in my life I used rm to delete something I didn't intend to...

`pwd`**:** `/media/storage/vod`
`ls`**:** `css html series music movies`

```
sudo rm *.QTFS
sudo rm -rf *.QTFS
```

What is the difference between these two above? I've filename specified. So will recursion look within all sub directories for *.QTFS or just inside current dir (vod)? I imagine later... so in this case recursion flag doesn't do anything, correct?

```
sudo rm -R *.QTFS series/*
```

This was my undoing command. Anyhow, so in this case I just gave rm two separate delete commands, correct?

first delete recursively *.QTFS, but this part only looks inside current dir (vod).
Second deletes recursively contents of series directory.

In essence I'm trying to understand if I deleted something beyond obvious damage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `-r` and `-R` are aliases for `--recursive`, which the [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/rm) describes as:

> remove directories and their contents recursively

If you do `rm -r file1 file2`, the option is passed to both files. Since the recursion only applies to directories (you can't recursively act on a single level), this would do little more than delete both files.

If you do `rm -r folder1 folder2`, it will recursively delete everything within those folders and the folders themselves.

As far as how [filename expansion aka globbing](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/globs) works, `*` means any number of characters, so `*.QTFS` means any file in `$PWD` ending with `.QTFS` and `service/*` means any file within the `$PWD/service` folder.

That being said, as long as that's what you wanted to delete, you should be fine.

Use `-i` or `--interactive` to force `rm` to ask for confirmation at every removal, or `-I` or `--interactive=once` to ask once if your command would remove four or more files, or would recursively remove files.

Use `-f` or `--force` to cause `rm` to silently ignore non-existent files, and to not prompt for confirmation before removing a read-only file or directory.

You might want to look into [`trash`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trash-cli) if you want an undelete command of sorts. It interacts with the trashcan, giving you the option to have a fallback if need be.

Comment: Thanks for your time explaining this :) "this would do little more than delete both files." what is that little more?

"means any file in $PWD ending with .QTFS" but only in pwd not recursively inside sub directories of pwd?

Comment: "this would do little more than delete both files." == "this will only delete the two files." any path not explicitly stated (e.g. `/root/scripts/`) will be assumed to be in `$PWD`. `rm -r *.QTFS` only affects `$PWD` while `rm -r service/*` would recurse.

Comment: @zwets derp and I thought I learned something new looking at the manpage last night. Fixed.

Comment: @wxl Almost. Fixed it a tiny bit more.

Answer (score 0):

1. switch "r" is used for allowing rm command to delete folders also including the files in it.
2. Switch "f" is to instruct rm to force fully delete the file. In this case if file or folder dos not exists, rm command will not give any error message.

Comment: None of this helps. I know how to read help / man pages. I had a specific question.